# Keep email message format using python email.message

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am using python to read from a file and write it in an email, but it is not keep the paragraph format.

The is what is in the file

```
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                    DB entries with corresponding Gitlab Repos (GOOD)
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Project               | Repo                          | Webhook                                                       |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| jup-siv               | cat                           | http://gtprod1.hughes.com:8080/project/parse_SPRs             |
| jup-siv               | dog                           | http://gtprod1.hughes.com:8080/project/parse_SPRs             |
| jup-siv               | fish                          | http://gtprod1.hughes.com:8080/project/parse_SPRs             |
| jup-siv               | big_dog                       | http://gtprod1.hughes.com:8080/project/parse_SPRs             |
| jup-siv               | shri                          | http://gtprod1.hughes.com:8080/project/parse_SPRs             |
```

This is what I see in email:

[image]

This is the code
msg = EmailMessage()

```
    subject = ""

    with open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY_PATH, OUTPUT_FILENAME), "r") as f:
        subject = f.readline()
        msg.set_content(subject + "\n\n" + f.read())

    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = SOURCE_EMAIL
    msg["To"] = DEST_EMAIL

    smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER)
    smtp_connection.send_message(msg)
    smtp_connection.quit()
```

Comment: I suppose you should fix your email client, to display text as monospaced font (e.g. with a filter with only mail coming from you). Or you should go ugly and format mail in html, so you can tell the email client to display is as monospace (but that would be complex, if you are just doing for debug)